# Can't I rollback just one action of an edit?

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I made a question, and a person with good intentions make 3 edits to my post. The editions (that are made directly without review from my part) are all good except for the first one, the first one makes *in my opinion* the question less clear, so I decided to take a look at the roll back option, but realized that the rollback just allow me to get to an specific point in the timeline, not discart one particular change.

If I rollback then I lose all the good edits made after the mistake so... have I to revert the unwanted edit manually or there is a way to discart some edit keeping the newer ones?

Comment: Just make your own edit, changing that bit. If the rest of the edit was good, is less work that way.

Comment: Use the [edit] button, in the bottom left corner of your question to edit it your self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't "reverse-apply one commit", only roll back to a specific past revision, exactly as it was. SO interface isn't quite up to TortoiseGit's standards yet :-)

Revert that edit by hand: press the "edit" button on the post as it is now and make the necessary changes manually. Given the clear outlining of changes in post history and the ability to see the exact markup, it's not so hard to do.

Comment: Ok, done. Would it worth it to make a feature request about this?

Comment: @Dknacht no-one stops you from trying, but I doubt there's enough demand to warrant the added complexity (e.g. an interface to resolve conflicts will need to be added, too, in case the patch doesn't apply cleanly; what about several commits?). SO posts and their history are orders of magnitude simpler and tolerant to edit mistakes than a code base, so it's easy and reliable enough to do things by hand.

Comment: @Dknacht just to confirm, [you've now rolled back to before all the edits by D-Shih](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51793025/revisions) instead of undoing just the one change by editing the post manually (which is what I meant by "revert that edit by hand"). Is this as intended?

Comment: Well I initially didn't know how rollback worked, so I tried it out. I did it before I posted the question.

Comment: @Dknacht okay, [I now applied the change for you to demonstrate how it's done](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51793025/10). (A rollback before that is not relevant; I did it to bring the post to the "initial state before you intended to make your change" -- for clarity.)

Comment: Ok, I've taken a look at that. thank you.